# Link in list group not opening when trigerred (Bootstrap carousel tweak)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap carousel in my website that I have tweaked to look like a "news slider", [see demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/272Lg28u/7/):

HTML :

```
<div id="slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://lorempixel.com/800/400">
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group col-sm-4">
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="list-group-item active">
      <h4 class="text-uppercase"><a href="http://www.google.fr">Link 1</a><br><small>Google FR</small></h4></li>
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="text-uppercase"><a href="http://www.google.de">Link 2</a><br><small>Google DE</small></h4></li>
    <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="2" class="list-group-item">
      <h4 class="text-uppercase"><a href="http://www.google.co.uk">Link 3</a><br><small>Google UK</small></h4></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#slider .list-group {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#slider .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#slider .list-group-item h4 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0;
}

#slider .list-group-item small {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
}

#slider .list-group-item.active,
#slider .list-group-item.active:focus,
#slider .list-group-item.active:hover {
  background-color: #C52026;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
}

#slider .list-group-item:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

#slider .list-group-item.active a,
#slider .list-group-item.active:focus a,
#slider .list-group-item.active:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}

#slider .list-group-item.active small,
#slider .list-group-item.active:focus small,
#slider .list-group-item.active:hover small {
  color: #bbb;
}

#slider .carousel-caption {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  text-shadow: none;
}

#slider .carousel-caption h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#slider .carousel-caption h2 small {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}
```

JS :

```
var clickEvent = false;
var slider = $('#slider');
slider.carousel({
  interval: 3000
}).on('click', '.list-group li', function() {
  clickEvent = true;
  $('.list-group li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  if (!clickEvent) {
    var count = $('.list-group').children().length - 1;
    var current = $('.list-group li.active');
    current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
    var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
    if (count == id) {
      $('.list-group li').first().addClass('active');
    }
  }
  clickEvent = false;
});
var slider = $('#slider');
var boxheight = slider.find('.carousel-inner').innerHeight();
var itemlength = slider.find('.item').length;
var triggerheight = boxheight / itemlength;
slider.find('.list-group-item').outerHeight(triggerheight);
```

The thing is, when I click the links on the title, they do not open...

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much, but even by removing all your JavaScript from the fiddle, the links won't open...
I guess something is disabling them, and the answer might lie in the documentation of your JS libraries.

However I was able to quickly enable the links by adding:

```
$('#slider h4').on('click', 'a', function(){
    window.open(this.href);
    return false;
})
```

Comment: ok I'll implement this while I still check what could be wrong. I'm only using bootstrap, nothing else.